# Mysql, dúvida sobre variaveis

Tags: mysql, sintaxe

o Mysql permite usar vários tipo de sintaxe na declaração de variaveis ex:

```
declare i int unsigned default 0;
set @str = "select ";
```

Tem alguma vantagem em usar um tipo ou outro, ou alguma desvantagem ou ainda alguma recomendação de quando usar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As variáveis com `@` são [*user-defined variables*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), e têm escopo de sessão. Ou seja, ela é válida do momento em que é aberta a conexão com o servidor, até o fechamento desse conexão.

As variáveis que você cria com [`DECLARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) são variáveis locais de uma função ou *stored procedure*, e são recriadas a cada chamada da função ou procedure onde estão declaradas.

Comment: Eu usava indiscriminadamente, já cheguei a fazer stored procedure com as duas e roda igual, mas então em suma quer dizer que as user-defined eu posso usa-las dentro de uma function ou sp e continuar com o valor dela em outra chamada de função ou sp se eu manter a conexão ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA isso mesmo

Answer (score -1):

Essa pergunta é bem pessoal, é o mesmo que perguntar a um desenvolvedor qual vantagem usar uma ou outra linguagem de programação, ele dira que "Depende do que você vai fazer, como vai fazer e porque vai fazer" e uma série de outras vantagens e desvantagens.

é sabido que certos tipos de declarações alocam mais memória e outras nem tanto, porém até mesmo as que alocam menos memória se consumidas de forma errada durante a execução do software arrebentarão com o seu servidor.

Aconselho que você leia este case e entendera melhor do que estou falando.

[Usando variáveis no MySQL](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/3071/mysql/usando-variaveis-no-mysql/)

Espero tê-lo ajudado (a melhor sintaxe é aquela que atende melhor a seus propósitos).

Comment: Não é pessoal neste caso, existe uma diferença entre as variáveis criadas com as duas sintaxes que ele indicou na pergunta.